# Xcode, Utilities tab not present

Tags: xcode7

The utilities tab in Xcode isn't showing up, it's just not appearing. When I stopped working on it a few hours ago, everything was fine. As I'm opening it now, the tab (the one on the extreme right) isn't on the screen. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

There is Hide or Show Utilities option box is there on the right side First of the XCode.If you click that it shows you and again if you click that it hides the utilities.Also see the below screenshots

When I click the Hide Or Show Utilities box,It opens

[image]

Now Again When I click that It hides the Utilities

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on top right corner to show or hide utility, It looks like below image

[image]

Click right most button!